# How to call java script function from mvc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Let say I have the following javascript

```
function blob(alertText) {
     alert(alertText);
}
```

I would like to call the function within my view. something like:

```
<% if (x == 0)
    //Need to Call the javascript function here. e.g. blob("sometext");
%>
```

How can I call the the javascript function within the enclosed if statement in my view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
<% if (x == 0) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">blob("sometext");</script>
<% } %>
```

Since the Javascript needs to be put on the page, you need to close off the `<% %>` tags so that you can print HTML. The specific HTML needs to be a `<script>` tag that calls the function you need.

Answer (score 1):

Put a script tag calling the javasript function inside the if statement:

```
<% if (x == 0) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">blob("sometext");</script>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you're not using Razor (because of your code sample), but if you want to use it at some time, you can do it like this

```
@if (x == 0)
{
<text>
    <script type="text/javascript">blob("sometext");</script>
</text>
}
```

or

```
@if (x == 0)
{
@:    <script type="text/javascript">blob("sometext");</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (x == 0)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">blob("sometext");</script>
}
```